# Get URL hash during click event/function

Tags: javascript, jquery

During a jQuery click event function, I understand the click event is fired before the underlying event is completed (and URL is updated)... so you can control the event.  Which means the hash of the link isn't yet available via `window.location.hash`

Is `e.target.hash` better than reaching into the `<a>` element itself to get the hash value; or passing the necessary variable via an `onclick` event? "Better" defined as cross-browser compatibility or more prone to errors.

For example:

```
<a class="accountLink" href="#account/123456">Account 123456</a>
```

```js
$('.accountLink').click(function(e){
  console.log(e.target.hash);
  console.log(window.location.hash);
});
```

Log:

```js
#account/123456
(blank on initial click)
```

https://jsfiddle.net/r1xpsut1/1/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given your requirements it sounds like the `onhashchange` event of the `window` would be more appropriate:

```
window.onhashchange = function() {
    alert(window.location.hash);
}
```

[**Updated fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/r1xpsut1/2/)

Comment: Perfect, thanks Rory!  One function watching for the hash update will definitely fit in this instance and help simplify.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Mozilla Web API](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Event/target), `Event.target` is supported in every modern browser, except for Internet Explorer 6 to 8 where `Event.srcElement` is used instead, so if you want to support it, you can use:

```
var target = (event.target || event.srcElement);
```

In fact, said `.event` property [is defined as](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/Comparison_of_Event_Targets):

> The DOM element on the lefthand side of the call that triggered this
>   event, eg:
>
> ```
> element.dispatchEvent(event)
> ```

It is therefore the same as reaching the `<a>` youself.